# Error for URL linking to CSS file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I'm beginner for PHP. Why I cannot link to the CSS file with these codes? What's wrong with my code? Could someone help me?

header.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap 3 responsive centered columns">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
    <script>
    var template_dir_js = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>";
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.slidertron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skel-layers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">         
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <noscript>
        <p><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/skel.css" /></p>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/fakeLoader.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/gravity-forms-bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/default.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/component.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation-flex.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/foundation.min.css" />
    </noscript>
</head>
```

Supposed to localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Beyond/css/style.css(correct URL) but now it links to localhost/wordpress/sample-page/css/style.css(wrong URL). How to change the link to correct URL? Wordpress can load my Javascript but it cannot load my CSS file.

[URL for linking CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG2BT.jpg)
[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WVyK.jpg)

Comment: You have bad formed tags before style links. Close all of your meta tags by `/>`

Comment: Why do you have one of your `<link />` inside a paragraph?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing the echo statement. Try changing this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
```

Does this help?

Comment: yes, but still cannot read the CSS file. What is the problem?

Comment: t.(anonymous function) @ skel.min.js:2
attachElement @ skel.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ skel.min.js:2
Object.keys.nn.(anonymous function) @ skel.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ skel.min.js:2
Object.keys.nn.(anonymous function) @ skel.min.js:2
attachElements @ skel.min.js:2
changeState @ skel.min.js:2
poll @ skel.min.js:2
init @ skel.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ init.js:9
(anonymous) @ init.js:77

Comment: try replacing `echo bloginfo(...);` with `echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` and let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the value of your template directory uri in a variable then use it in the program.if it is not coming just echo the value of $template_dir and post it here

   ```
    <?php
     $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $template_dir;?>/css/style.css" />
   ```